# Not sure if I can use array_intersect or array_search in this case

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, operators

I have an array (`$entry`) that could have either of two sets of keys:

```
"custom_0_first" AND "custom_0_last";
```

OR

```
"custom_1_first" AND "custom_1_last";
```

I'm trying to do the following, but it doesn't seem to be setting the variables:

```
$firstname = array_search('custom_0_first', $entry) || array_search('custom_1_first', $entry);
$lastname = array_search('custom_0_last', $entry) || array_search('custom_1_last', $entry);
```

Note that `$entry['custom_0_first']` does work fine. I was trying to avoid an IF statement here.

Is my understanding of how array_search or `PHP` works incorrect? As I understand it, if the first `array_search` doesn't find the key, the function returns `FALSE` and then it will check the right side of the `OR` statement. Is this incorrect? I saw `array_intersect` that I thought might work, but it looks like that doesn't work with arrays with associative keys.

Comment: please, show var_dump($entry)

Comment: array_search() finds value, not key

Comment: @splash58 Yes, I want the value, not the key. If the key exists, I want the value belonging to `custom_0_first` otherwise the value belonging to `custom_1_first`

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding properly, but if `'custom_0_first'`, `'custom_0_last'`, etc. are possible _keys_ of `$entry`, then `array_search()` will not find them.

Comment: @Don'tPanic You are correct. I misunderstood array_search. I though it was searching for a key and if that key was found, would return its value. Looks like I'm going back to good ol' `isset` and `?:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array_intersect_key to get the values you're looking for. It returns an array. You can get the first (theoretically only) element of the resulting array using reset. It will give a strict standards notice "Only variables should be passed by reference" but it will work.

```
$first = reset(array_intersect_key($entry, ['custom_0_first' => 0, 'custom_1_first' => 0]));
$last = reset(array_intersect_key($entry, ['custom_0_last' => 0, 'custom_1_last' => 0]));
```

Another way to do it would be to just check for the key using isset.

```
$first = isset($entry['custom_0_first']) ? $entry['custom_0_first'] : $entry['custom_1_first'];
$last = isset($entry['custom_0_last']) ? $entry['custom_0_last'] : $entry['custom_1_last'];
```

Comment: I was trying to so something a little more terse and elegant than the ternary, but I think I'm going to go with the simple solution. :) Thanks.

Comment: @Armstrongest Not that it's very useful to most of us right now, but in PHP 7 we'll have `??` to handle these things. Pretty cool. :)

Comment: Yeah, I have used the null coalescing operator in C# since it was introduced in C# 2.0. It's one of my most popular questions on SO. Glad to see it come to PHP , for sure!

Answer (score 2):

Unlike in JavaScript, the `||` operator always returns a boolean value. Replace it with the `?:` operator.

`$a ?: $b` is actually short syntax for `$a ? $a : $b`, see [ternary operator](http://php.net/ternary#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

> The expression `(expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3)` evaluates to `expr2` if `expr1` evaluates to `TRUE`, and `expr3` if `expr1` evaluates to `FALSE`.
>
> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression `expr1 ?: expr3` returns `expr1` if `expr1` evaluates to `TRUE`, and `expr3` otherwise.

Comment: This is what was throwing me for a loop. Thanks. I was thinking in javascript again.

Comment: I should be able to use: 

`$firstname = array_search('custom_0_first', $entry) ?: array_search('custom_1_first', $entry);` then, right? I'm going to test that out.

Comment: I just realize that I'd understood `array_search` incorrectly as it searches values, not key names. doh!